# How can I prevent selection of UITableView from changing when details change and the tableview reorders?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In a core data app, I've got a UIViewController that has a "master" tableview on the left, with a set of detail controls (textfields, switches) and another UITableview on the right. (This is the iPad layout.) The tableviews are populated by NSFetchedResultsController instances. When the user selects a row on the leftmost tableview, it populates the details fields accordingly for editing, and the far right table is populated by another NSFetchedResultsController, displaying a set of related objects.

My problem is that for the master tableview, the one on the left, whenever I edit on of the fields related to the sort descriptors of the NSFetchedREsultsController, the table reorders and changes it's selection, which means the user would have to find the desired row and select it again to continue working. Is there a way I can prevent that selection from changing, or at least force it to reselect the proper row after it reorders the data?

Comment: Isn't this just the sort of problem discussed by Apple in regard to the fetched results controller delegate? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are implementing the fetched results controller's delegate in only the most basic way, i.e. calling `reloadData` from within the `controllerDidChangeContent:` method. This will clear the table view's selection.

It you implement the fine-grained delegate methods, you should receive multiple changes of type `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` during a reordering update, from which you can call `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`, which should preserve the table view's selection.

Otherwise you can store the model object that is selected in `controllerWillChangeContent:` and restore the selection from that model object in `controllerDidChangeContent:`.

Comment: What ended up working for me was that I was already strong the selected object as a property of the view controller, so in controllerDidChangeContent I had the tableView select the row that object was found in. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!